# Posgresql LAG with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data looks like this:

| id | user | data | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-05 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2023-02-05 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-06 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2023-02-07 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 2023-02-07 |

I want to get a difference between data of each row and a previous row for this user like this:

| id | user | data | date | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-05 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2023-02-05 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-06 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2023-02-07 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 2023-02-07 | 4 |

I can do this with LAG function but without condition that users for difference must be same. How can I do it with condition in postgres?

Comment: `lag()` is a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), so you can add `partition by user` to the window definition - that way each user gets a separate partition and window context.

Comment: and add an order by.  Order of rows are not guarantteed so how do you want the rows ordered?

Comment: @Zegarek thanks. I should look into documentation more carefully >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `LAG()` as follows:

```sql
SELECT id, user, data, date,
       data - LAG(data) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date) AS diff
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date, user;
```

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek answered in comments before you, but he didn't put it as an answer, so I will mark your as a solution when will be able.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374919/posgresql-lag-with-condition?noredirect=1#comment132999695_75374919): [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) let you [partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) your input, narrowing down the context of each window the way you want it:

```sql
select *, 
       coalesce(data-(lag(data) over w1),0) as data_diff
from   test
window w1 as (partition by user order by date asc) 
order by date, 
        "user";
```

It's also handy to define the window separately to save space and handle `null` for first row in case of `lag()` or last row for `lead()` with [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jtLnMkgU)